# Best way to run a Meteor method regularly, but not too often?

Tags: javascript, meteor

What is the best, most efficient way to have reasonably fresh data from a Meteor method without having it run constantly?

I have a server side Meteor method that must check 3-4 collections to return the right set of values.

We use this method in several places throughout the app, but it seems really expensive to run often.

Here's the method:

```
getContactLimit() {
  let currentOrg   = Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().profile && Meteor.user().profile.currentOrg,
      orgData      = Orgs.findOne( { 'domain': currentOrg } ),
      orgStatus    = orgData && orgData.status,
      orgPlan      = orgData && orgData.billing && orgData.billing.plan,
      allPlans     = Meteor.settings.public.plans,
      thisPlan     = _.find( allPlans, function(plan){ return plan.name == orgPlan; } ),
      planContacts = thisPlan && thisPlan.contacts,
      contactCount = Contacts.find({ 'orgId': currentOrg }).count(),
      countObj     = {
        planCount: planContacts,
        orgCount: contactCount
      };
  return countObj;
}
```

Currently we just call it on-demand, and it hasn't been a problem. But we're about to add it to display notifications throughout the app.

One way I've looked at is calling the method wrapped in a `Meteor.setInterval();` function and having it update a session variable.

Here's how I am thinking of calling it:

```
Meteor.setInterval(function() {
  Meteor.call( 'getContactLimit', function( error, response ) {
    Session.set('contactLimit', response );
  });    
}, 60000 );
```

Another possibility is embedding it in certain actions, so it only gets run on specific activities, but that feels hacky.

Any ideas? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: We use the [synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron) library for chores similar to this, hopefully it can be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a custom publish function within which I would run `this.changed` at a set interval. See the counts-by-room example in the docs of publish (http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html). You could use one of the cron packages to schedule the interval.

Then the client doesn't need to know about this hack and can just subscribe to the custom publication like any other.